# VS Code Material Icon Theme like icons for Windows File Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code, icons, themes, explorer

I use VS Code [Material Icon Theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PKief.material-icon-theme) and it shows different icons for different file types and folder names.
Is there any Icon Pack or something for Windows File Explorer or A different file manager that gives icons for code files?
It will save a lot of time finding your files files and folders in big workspaces.
Thanks!

Comment: Just thought the same. Did you find anything?

Comment: I Couldn't, It would be really helpful but I could not find anything.